# Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined - code works, but annoing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

It shows this error in the console, but the code is working:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined

How to fix this error?

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= buttonsCount; i += 1) {
  buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
    if (this.id == "plus") {
      var pret_unitar_euro = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_unitar_euro']").val($(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='input_value']").val() * $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_unitar_euro_h']").val());
      var pret_unitar_lei = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_unitar_lei']").val($(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='input_value']").val() * $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_unitar_lei_h']").val());
      var pret_total_euro = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_total_euro']").val($(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='input_value']").val() * $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_total_euro_h']").val());
      var pret_total_lei = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_total_lei']").val($(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='input_value']").val() * $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_total_lei_h']").val());
    } else if (this.id == "minus") {
      var pret_unitar_euro = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_unitar_euro']").val($(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_unitar_euro_h']").val() * $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='input_value']").val());
      var pret_unitar_lei = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_unitar_lei']").val($(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_unitar_lei_h']").val() * $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='input_value']").val());
      var pret_total_euro = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_total_euro']").val($(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_total_euro_h']").val() * $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='input_value']").val());
      var pret_total_lei = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_total_lei']").val($(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='pret_total_lei_h']").val() * $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='input_value']").val());

    }
  };
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="minus" id="minus">-</button>
<button type="button" class="plus" id="plus">+</button>
```

Comment: In your html file, are your button tags before your script tags ? Your script tag must be after your button been declared in your DOM

Comment: You should really store the selected elements in a variable. You could cut down the number of DOM accesses you're making by around 50%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition is not correct. You are getting the error on last iteration as `buttons[i]` is `undefined`.

*Use*

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttonsCount; i += 1) {
}
```

instead of

```
for (var i = 0; i <= buttonsCount; i += 1) {
}
```

---

As you are using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), it can be used to attach event handler, then `for` loop will not be required.

```
$("button").on('click', function(e) {
  //Your code
});
```

Comment: Yep, this. If there are 5 buttons, the `buttonsCount` length will be 5, but it's trying to get `buttons[5]` which is the _sixth_ button, and is non-existent.

Comment: I need a for loop because the buttons are in a php while loop.

Answer (score 3):

> How to fix this error?

You need to fix the **condition** in your for loop as

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttonsCount; i += 1) { //using < instead of <=
```

since when `i` becomes equal to `buttonCount`, then `buttons[i]` becomes `undefined` since you are trying to access an item from array which array doesn't have.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understood.